# Django Choicefield from a list

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, django-forms

i have a small question about forms.

So how i would usually create a choice form would be this way:

```
Metric_name_CHOICES = [
        ('Transfer', 'Transfer'),
        ('RFI/RFD', 'RFI/RFD'),
        ('...', '...')
    ]
Metric_name = forms.ChoiceField(choices=correct_associate_action_CHOICES, widget=forms.Select)
```

Which is a great method, but what if I wanted the list of choices to come from a list in a model?

I guess something like:

```
Metric_name = forms.ChoiceField(choices=dv_model.objects.get(Metric_name_dv), widget=forms.Select)
```

So to take all the fields inside a column in a model, and display them as a drop down field.

Comment: Why don't you use ForeignKey, it would match your needs perfectly

Comment: @Kholdarbekov: this deals with a *form*, this is not per se a form that is constructed based on a model. A `ForeignKey` is something used in a model, and by default works with a `ModelChoiceField` at the form layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that case you use a [**`ModelChoiceField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield). This is a `ChoiceField` but where the choices represent model objects. This is the default form field for a `ForeignKey` for example.

You thus can implement this with:

```
Metric_name = forms.ModelChoiceField(
    queryset=dv_model.objects.all(),
    widget=forms.Select
)
```

It will use as key item the primary key of the `dv_model` object, and as option text the outcome of `str(…)` on that model object.

Answer (score 1):

I basically do like this for Choice Field:

**In models.py file:**

```
Metric_name_CHOICES = (
        ('Transfer', 'Transfer'),
        ('RFI/RFD', 'RFI/RFD'),
        ('...', '...')
    )

Metric_name = models.CharField(max_length=70,choices=Metric_name_CHOICES,default="")
```

**If you want to pass default value you can choose from your choices**

**And in the forms.py:**

```
'Metric_name ': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
```

***Hope It helps you....***